# How can I set up Google Event tracking on a button using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-analytics

I'm working with a WordPress site, and I have a button that needs to have google event tracking set up so that google can track the number of clicks on the button.

Usually I just add the onclick function to the button in the markup like this.

```
<button onclick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘Rate it Now Form’, ‘Clicked’);” >
   <a href=”/rater-form/” class=”cont_no”>Rate it Now!</a>
</button>
```

However this button is being generated by Gravity Forms so its not in the mark up.

I know how to use the .click event in jQuery, the issue I'm having is how do I get googles code to function properly with the jQuery .click event?

Would it be easier to somehow inject the

```
onclick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘Rate it Now Form’, ‘Clicked’);”
```

into the dynamic button?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding, you're looking for how to write the GA code in a javascript/jQuery file instead of html. This ought to work...

```
$('button').click(function(){
   ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘Rate it Now Form’, ‘Clicked’);
});
```

You will probably want to use a more specific selector than "button". Sounds like you already know you need to have the GA script in your head.

Comment: Yeah I have other events on the site already I was just having an issue with this on because its the dynamic button. I actually finally ended up find this solution just after I posted the question, and realized its pretty simple. I'm using this right now but still cant get it to work.  Edit: I'm not getting any errors either, its just not tracking.

Comment: Well first thing I'd do is make sure the button is registering the click event: 
$('button').click(function(){
  alert('button has been clicked');
});

Comment: Good call, yeah its not even registering the click.

Comment: Here's my code $('#btnRate').click(function(){ alert('button has been clicked'); });

Comment: So maybe there's an issue with jQuery. Does the click function fire if you write it in vanilla js like so? 
`var myButton = document.getElementById("btnRate");

myButton.onclick = function() {
 alert("hello");
};`